# SQL Query for repeat advertisers

Tags: sql

I want to identify first time and repeat advertisers.
This is the code I had written,
but I am getting duplicate values and the advertiser's first order is flagged as a new customer and the subsequent ones as repeat.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (order_id )
              , advertiser_id
              , advertiser_name
              , order_start_date
              , source_type
              , MIN(order_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY advertiser_id) AS firstorderdate    
              , CASE WHEN (order_start_date) = (firstorderdate) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS isNewCustomer,
 FROM advertising;
```

Current output

```
Advertiser isnewcustomer
A            0
A            1
B            0
C            0
D            1
D            1
```

Expected output

```
Advertiser  isnewcustomer
A            1
B            0
C            0
D            1
```

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a sample data. Have you tried using MIN and GROUP BY instead of PARTITION BY?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Strange, you select 7 columns, but your current output has only 2 columns.

Comment: `DISTINCT`  **is not a function**, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT order_id, advertiser_id, ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Provide the exact output you have. you may make the values random if you don't want to show original

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select subqry.advertiser_id,
case when subqry.adv_count > 1 Then  1
ELSE 0 
END as isNewCustomer FROM

( select advertiser_id, count(advertiser_id) as adv_count
from advertising
group by advertiser_id ) subqry;
```